# how to sprout around a turtle in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I have been looking to spread around turtles and I don't get it.

The idea is that I have an insect population (a type of turtle) and this insect population check around if there's a nesting patch available. If there's one and  there's no other insect population I would like this patch to generate a new insect population. So far I have come with this idea :

```
ask insect-populations 
[
    ask patches in-radius 2 
    [
        if lay? = 1 
        [
            if not any? insect-populations [ask self [sprout-insect-populations 1]]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Thanks in advance for any tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ask insect-populations     
[
ask patches in-radius 2 with [lay? = 1 and not any? insect-populations-here]   
[sprout-insect-populations 1]
]
```

should be what you want if I understand your intent correctly.
The trick is in the **[with]**. It takes a true/false block. So any agent for which the boolean statement inside the square brackets is included in the set.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly except for the fact I had to put `not` before `any` in order to get the desired effect but overall, giving that you don't have a clue about what I'am doing that's just great!

Comment: As I said, it is no problem at all, it was just a minor correction and the solution you proposed worked perfectly. Thanks again